# Error inflating FloatingActionButton in API 19

Tags: android

I already found many same questions, but the answer was always that the AppTheme doesn't inherit from AppCompat-theme or that a false backgroundTint parameter was used or that support library was missing.

But neither applies to my code.

On API 23 it is working great.

## Fragment Code

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

@BindView(R.id.name_add)
FloatingActionButton add;
@BindView(R.id.names_list)
SwipeMenuListView namesListView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_names, container, false);
    }

    protected View inflate(LayoutInflater inflater, int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(resource, root, attachToRoot); // Error occurs at this line
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        return view;
    }
```

## fragment.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.names.NamesFragment">

    <com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView
        android:id="@+id/names_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/name_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/app_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

## styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

## build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cherry_wave.nmg"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

def android_support_version = '24.1.1'
def butterknife_version = '8.0.1'
def lombok_version = '1.12.6'
def parceler_version = '1.1.1'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${butterknife_version}"
    apt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:${butterknife_version}"
    provided "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombok_version}"
    apt "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombok_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${android_support_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${android_support_version}"
    compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${android_support_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${android_support_version}"
    compile "org.parceler:parceler-api:${parceler_version}"
    apt "org.parceler:parceler:${parceler_version}"
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.9'
    compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
}
```

## Full Error Log

```
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:621)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                     at cherry_wave.nmg.NMGFragment.inflate(NMGFragment.java:15)
                                                     at cherry_wave.nmg.view.names.NamesFragment.onCreateView(NamesFragment.java:37)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1632)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:637)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
                                                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1237)
                                                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1085)
                                                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1611)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:671)
                                                     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:738)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:74
```

Comment: can you put Fragment code? I guess you not register ButterKnife;

Comment: I tried it now on API 24-19, all working except 19.

Comment: Would really appreciate an answer =(